# Exclude constraint with partial index - Postgresql

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
class Slot(models.Model):
    time_range = models.DateTimeRangeField()
    calendar = models.ForeignKey('Calendar')
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaign', null=True)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    calendar = models.ForeignKey('Calendar')
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaign', null=True)
    slot = models.ForeignKey('Slot', models.DO_NOTHING, unique=True, null=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

I want to make `Slot.time_range` unique so not other slot overlap with it but just is that slot have an appointment.

I have the following SQL so far

```
 ALTER TABLE appointments_slot
   ADD CONSTRAINT time_range_unique
   EXCLUDE USING gist (time_range WITH &&)
   WHERE (MISSING PART);
```

Is there any way to join or something here, I have tried many ways without success. Maybe I will finish adding an `appointment_id` column to `Slot` table.

Comment: Is that a one-to-one relationship? Since I don't know django, could you add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for my benefit?